# Why is my particle system rendering particles in the wrong spot

Tags: rendering, particles

I have an emitter here set to face but the particles are shifted to the right somehow.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps your object used for rendering has it's mesh offset from its origin?

Comment: Yep that was it